# How well can a rotation separate lattice vectors of equal norm in Z^d?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lattices

I'm interested in rotations $R$ that maximally separate integral lattice vectors of equal norm. This question is preliminary, and regards the scaling of those separations as norm goes to infinity.

Let $\mathbb{Z}^d$ be the usual cubic lattice in $d$ dimensions. What is the smallest (infimum) exponent $e(d) > 0$ for which there exists a constant $c(d) > 0$ and rotation $R \in SO(d)$, such that for any two cubic lattice points $x$ and $y$ of equal norm $\lVert x \rVert = \lVert y \rVert = r$, the angle between $x$ and $Ry$ is $> c(d) r^{-e(d)}$?

I have indirect arguments that $e(d) > 1/2$.

Comment: To be clear, you allow $x=y$?

Comment: Yes, $x = y$ is allowed.

Comment: I guess  $ r $  is fixed ... Otherwise you get no such bound .... (just take the vectors  $ (m,\pm 1,0,0,...) $) and you get  $ c(d) = 0  $ .

Comment: @few_reps I don't see how that sequence of vectors forces $c(d) = 0$. For instance in $d = 2$, if take $R$ to be rotation by $\pi/4$, then $\cos{\theta_{x,Ry}}$ is irrational for all pairs of equal-norm $x$ and $y$...

Comment: Then I probably misunderstood what you call $\mathrm{SO}(d)$ ... do you mean orthogonal matrices with integers as coefficients ?

Comment: Should be $e(d)=1$. In one direction just use the standard Dirichlet argument on simultaneous rational approximations. In the other direction (for even $d$, at least) write $\mathbb R^d=(\mathbb R^2)^{d/2}$ and apply the rotation by $45^\circ$ in each two-dimensional space.

Comment: @few_reps No, I meant regular orthogonal matrices. But there is a single $R$ that rotates all $y$.

Comment: @fedja I think I understand your idea, but it does not give me $e(d) = 1$. Did you mean $e(d) = 2$ instead? For instance, with the $45^{\circ}$ rotation in $d=2$, consider $x = (p,q)$ and $y = (q,p)$, where $p/q$ is a convergent of $1 + \sqrt{2}$. The angle between $x$ and $Ry$ goes like $r^{-2}$.

Comment: @ChaitanyaMurthy ok, sorry, I see now

Comment: @ChaitanyaMurthy Ah, sorry. I thought you were talking about the **distance**, not the angle. Then, indeed, $e(d)=2$ (I presume that the quantifier on $r$ is "for every $r$" here; for a fixed $r$ the answer may be somewhat different (or, maybe, not).

Comment: @fedja No problem! I do mean "for every $r$". Is it clear, however, that $e(d) = 2$ is best possible in all $d = 2n$? Can we do no better even if the rotation hyperplanes do not line up with $\mathbb{Z}^2$ factors? It is not obvious to me that Dirichlet rules this out.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Dirichlet tells you that for every $r>0$ there is an integer point $x$ with $|x|\le r$ such that $Rx$ is integer with precision about $d/r$. This is *almost* enough to conclude that the norm of the integer approximation $y$ to $Rx$ is the same but not quite. I believe this small issue can be fixed but, apparently, I need more time for that.